# Identify software used to create app imported from github

Tags: android, github

I imported an android app source code from github to Android Studio hoping to understand and modify it. However, turns out the app was created using some app creator and frameworks were involved. So the code was not very user friendly.How to identify what software was used to create the app so that i can open it in the same and modify it?

Comment: Can you share the link to that GItHub repository?

Comment: There's no magic way of doing that.  You basically have to look at the code and know enough frameworks to guess.

Comment: here's what i am working on https://github.com/nextgis/android_gisapp

Comment: the title says **GIS**

Comment: My main am is to import the gis app project into android studio and modify it.